# why do not the programe moving ahead?

Tags: perl

[image]

I do write a practice perl script from book is not running ahead from 2nd line
it remaining on on line anybody can tell me what is the problem in the programe.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You have a `while` loop reading input. How does your book say to run the program? Press `Ctrl+D` to get out of it and then re-read the text associated with the code in the book.